# Android .apk upload into market

Tags: android

1.What is the procudure for uploading android app into market.
2. Can we upload multiple apks with single market account.
3.What is the life time for the market account?
4. what else settings required for this?

Pl help me on this.

Thanks
Vakiti

Comment: This kind of questions are useless... do a google search first please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 . you have to create a developer account

2 . open developer console and upload you apk

3 . yes you can upload different apps with one account

Answer (score 0):

Read this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

It'll tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think every answer you can find on this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html